# What Is correct way of updating ContentItem in Orchard?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I am trying to update a specific part with following code:

```
var nationalPart = _contentManager.Get<NationalPart>(Id);      
nationalPart.Name = part.Name;
```

i have already done this.but now it is not working.even i call `contentManager.Flush()` explicitly, but still no luck. can anyone help me with this?
thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: i found where my problem originates from!
      when i make a JSON request to update a contentPart.the in memory version is updating but  it is not reflecting the result to db.now we are one step closer to answer.but what is preventing the session from updating the db?

**EDIT2:**

this is code for my handler :

```
        public NationalPartHandler(IRepository<NationalPartRecord> repository)
        {
            Filters.Add(StorageFilter.For(repository));
        }
```

this is code for Controller Action:

```
    [GridAction(EnableCustomBinding = true)]
    public JsonResult UpdateNational(NationalViewModel Model, GridCommand Command)
    {
         if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return new JsonResult { Data = "error" };
        var NationalPart = _contentmanager.Get(Model.Id).As<NationalPart>();
        NationalPart.Record = new NationalPartRecord();
        NationalPart.Record.MapFrom<NationalPartRecord, NationalViewModel>(Model);
        _soccerService.UpdateNational(NationalPart);         
        return NationalsListJson(Command);
    }
```

and finally code for service:

```
public void UpdateNational(NationalPart part)
{
    var nationalPart = _contentManager.Get<NationalPart>(part.Id);      
    nationalPart.Name = part.Name;
    _contentManager.Flush();
}
```

Comment: Did you remember to have your part property setter set the value of the property in your record class?  I've forgotten this before.

Comment: If it's not working, you probably have an exception somewhere rolling back the transaction. Check app_data\logs.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy I have double checked the logs directory.but it is empty(there is no error).

Comment: @BrandonJoyce I am sure every thing is OK.cause i successfully can add a new record.the problem is with updating the part.

Comment: i have edited my post.please check it again.many thanks for your help.

Comment: @BehnamEsmaili Try to check if the value you're setting is not being overwritten later on (eg. from a handler or sth). Also check if the setter for `nationalPart.Name` is doing `this.Record = value`. Please post the code for the handler and the part driver so we can get more info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the line

```
NationalPart.Record = new NationalPartRecord();
```

The underlying record is automatically generated and is proxied so NHibernate can save the data to the database whenever you do any change to it. You don't want to replace that ever, otherwise no data will get saved.

`UpdateNational` is redundant and you can remove it - you already have `part.Name` (which if I understand correctly, should map to part.Record.Name) set during call to `record.MapFrom`.

So the correct version would look like this

```
[GridAction(EnableCustomBinding = true)]
public JsonResult UpdateNational(NationalViewModel Model, GridCommand Command)
{
     if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return new JsonResult { Data = "error" };
    var part = _contentmanager.Get(Model.Id).As<NationalPart>();
    part.Record.MapFrom<NationalPartRecord, NationalViewModel>(Model);        
    return NationalsListJson(Command);
}
```

given your NationalPart looks similar to:

```
public NationalPart : ContentPart<NationalPartRecord>
{
    public string Name {
        get { return Record.Name; }
        set { Record.Name = value; }
    }
}
```

Summarizing - if you want to store some data in Orchard, all you need to do is to **set a value of some property of a record**, nothing more. Data will get persisted at the end of a request (or earlier, if you call `IContentManager.Flush()`).

Comment: many thanks to you.in fact that line was a stupid code that i forgot to remove.

Comment: @BehnamEsmaili No problem, happens;) Glad it helped.

Comment: @Piotr Szmyd Today method Flush() is not present in interface IContentManager. Can you give us an updated option please?